# Access violation in Breadth First Search

Tags: c, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I've written this code for BFS, but after showing the result it crashes. I don't find anything wrong with my code. Here's the code

I think this is pointer related problem, because I got the same problem because I did not allocate memeory. Visual studio debugger shows there's a problem in this function.

```
int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int vertexIndex) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; ++j) {
        if (adjMatrix[vertexIndex][j] == 1 && vertices[j]->visited == false) { //Is there anything wrong in this logic? 
            return j; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. This is my full code. DFS is working, its BFS that causing problems.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 50

int vertexCount;
struct vertex {
    char label;
    bool visited;
};
struct vertex *vertices[SIZE];
int adjMatrix[SIZE][SIZE];
int stack[SIZE];
int queue[SIZE];
int top = -1;
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;

void menu();
void addVertex();
void addEdges();
void push(char);
void pop();
void enQueue(char);
int deQueue();
void displayAdjMatrix();
void displayVertex(int);
int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int);
void DFS();
void BFS();
bool isStackEmpty();
bool isQueueEmpty();

int main() {
    menu();
    addVertex();
    addEdges();
    puts("\nDepth first search:");
    DFS();
    puts("\nBreadth first search:");
    BFS();
}

void menu() {
    puts("How many vertices?");
    scanf("%d", &vertexCount);
}
void addVertex() {
    int ascii = (int)'A';
    puts("Vertices are:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i, ++ascii) {
        vertices[i] = (struct vertex*)calloc(vertexCount, sizeof(struct vertex));
        vertices[i]->label = (char)ascii;
        vertices[i]->visited = false;
        printf("%c ", vertices[i]->label);
    }
}
void addEdges() {
    puts("\nEnter edges:");
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vertexCount; ++j) {
            printf("%c->%c: ", vertices[i]->label, vertices[j]->label);
            scanf("%d", &adjMatrix[i][j]);
            if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
                adjMatrix[j][i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
void displayAdjMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", adjMatrix[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

void push(char data) {
    if (top == SIZE - 1) {
        puts("Overflow!");
        return;
    }
    stack[++top] = data;
}

void pop() {
    if (top == -1) {
        puts("Underflow!");
        return;
    }
    stack[top--];
}

int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int vertexIndex) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; ++j) {
        if (adjMatrix[vertexIndex][j] == 1 && vertices[j]->visited == false) {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void displayVertex(int vertexIndex) {
    printf("%c ", vertices[vertexIndex]->label);
}

void DFS() {
    vertices[0]->visited = true;
    displayVertex(0);
    push(0);
    while (!isStackEmpty()) {
        int unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(stack[top]);
        if (!unvisitedVertex) {
            pop();
        }
        else {
            vertices[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
            displayVertex(unvisitedVertex);
            push(unvisitedVertex);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        vertices[i]->visited = false;
    }
}

bool isStackEmpty() {
    if (top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool isQueueEmpty() {
    if (front == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void enQueue(char data) {
    if (rear == SIZE - 1) {
        puts("Queue is full!");
        return;
    }
    if (front == -1) {
        ++front;
    }
    queue[++rear] = data;
}

int deQueue() {
    if (front == - 1) {
        puts("Queue is empty!");
        return 0;
    }
    int deleted;
    deleted = queue[front];
    queue[front++] = 0;
    return deleted;
}
void BFS() {
    vertices[0]->visited = true;
    displayVertex(0);
    enQueue(0);
    while (!isQueueEmpty()) {
        int temp = deQueue();
        int unvisitedVertex;
        while(unvisitedVertex = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(temp)) {
            vertices[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
            displayVertex(unvisitedVertex);
            enQueue(unvisitedVertex);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
        vertices[i]->visited = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea for how long the first while loop in BFS() is supposed to work? I debugged your code and the problem is within the while loop. It runs for a very long time and then creates a segmentation fault.

Comment: Look at definition of stack, when you push item (top++), when you pop item (top--), ok, it works. Now, look at definition of queue, when `front` will be -1 (excluding initialization)? You always do `front++`, but in `isQueueEmpty` the following condition is checked `front == -1`.

Comment: In `isQueueEmpty()`, you are checking condition `if (front == -1)` but in you whole program nowhere you are decrementing `front` but only incrementing it. Because of this, your while loop in `BSF()` will not terminate and ultimately the at one stage program is giving access violation. You need to check the logic of your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the deQueue() and isQueueEmpty() functions.